# No ack for postMessage cookie_check (Onepage Checkout error)

Tags: error, onepage-checkout, paypal

In onepage checkout page, in browser's console, I can see the following error

**Error: No ack for postMessage cookie_check .......... post-robot.js:268:32**

This is a file located here https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/static/js/post-robot.js. The error is occuring even if I disable Paypal as Payment Method.

Here's the part of that file that's consoling the error:

```
setTimeout(function () {
                if (!options.ack) {
                    return reject(new Error('No ack for postMessage ' + options.name));
                }
            }, _conf.CONFIG.ACK_TIMEOUT);
```

I have no idea what it means or how to fix it. Can you help me?